# Iterating over Web Elements using selenium Python , always excepts the second item

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to iterate and click over a list of webElements using Selenium with python .the first element always goes fine, but the second's click always throws an exception.
I checked the list and the list consists all the elements that I really want to click on, I have done that by printing their href attributes.

Here is my code:

```
for img in imgs:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.get(img.get_attribute('href'))
        # img.click()
        # I tried both click and driver.get and doesn't worked.

    except:
        print("something went wrong")
        continue
        # always second iteration enters here

    driver.back()
```

May the Helpers be blessed:)

Comment: Which type of error are you getting?

Comment: If possible share the site you are trying to navigate, or the action that takes place when you "click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hrefs = [ img.get_attribute("href") for img in Imgs]

for href in hrefs:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        href.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue


    driver.back()
```

1. Always print your Exception, don't just catch it and print something that doesn't make any sense
2. if you are clicking on some href link after the first click the page might have navigated to the link so second element no longer exists and your code works

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, Im pretty new to Python and Selenium.

Comment: what is the reason for 2 ? why objects no longer exist after clicking only one webElement ?

Comment: Say you have a link called facebook , you click it so it will navigate to facebook . Now elements in Imgs no longer available as you are in a different page . You should get stale or element not found error

Comment: You can avoid this by getting href from all Imgs first and storing it to an array and then click it

Comment: Updated the answer